# Is this a USBasp I can use with Arduino?

Tags: isp

I bought the following USBasp off of Aliexpress.

[image]
[image]

The Arduino UDE doesn't recognize it. When I try to run avrdude with it, it says:

```
avrdude -cusbasp -Pusb -patmega328p
avrdude: error: could not find USB device with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc vendor='www.fischl.de' product='USBasp'
```

Looking at the USB enumeration, it says:

USBHID:

```
  Product ID:   0xc8b4
  Vendor ID:    0x03eb  (Atmel Corporation)
  Version:  1.00
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: zhifengsoft
  Location ID:  0x14200000 / 8
  Current Available (mA):   1000
  Current Required (mA):    100
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Looking online, I see one blog post (http://www.sciencetronics.com/greenphotons/?p=938) about a device with the same VID/PID, and it says it can be reprogrammed but is not clear how to do it.

In particular, I know there is a jumper that I need to set to put it in self-programming mode but I can't figure out where to put this jumper. Once the jumper is in, I understand I just match the SPI pins and program it using the firmware.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a USBasp, that's some other programmer that has co-opted Atmel's vendor ID invalidly. If you want to use it then you will need to find and use some program called "ProgISP" that is only available for Windows.

That particular device does not show the jumper required for reprogramming, so I wouldn't attempt it (and in fact I would find the nearest bin to toss it in and get a couple from Baite and/or LC Tech instead).